# Auto update of UDF (at BP Ref) i.e Numatcard

Tags: sapb1

I tried to update UDF using a Formatted Search with following query:

`SELECT $[ORDR.numatcard]`

It's not updating when NUMATCARD gets changed, or when I create a new Sales order it doesn't take the respective NUMATCARD ref instead it repeats the same number that was saved in last sales order.

I also tried to choose auto refresh when field changes at "BP Reference NO" from drop down menu of the [User-Defined Values Setup:
[image: User-Defined Values Setup].

Comment: What version are you running? I've replicated your setup on SAP B1 9.1 PL05 and it's working just fine. Can you also include the exact query that you've got saved in the Query Manager? The name in the formatted search suggests that it may not be just `SELECT $[ORDR.numatcard]`

Comment: SAP Business One 9.1 (9.10.180) PL: 08  (32-bit) and yes the same query i'm using SELECT $[ORDR.numatcard].